# major() and minor() give different numbers from ls

Tags: c, linux

Part of my C program is to output whether two device files are equal (i.e., same kind of device file and same major and minor numbers). It outputted that `tty` and `tty2` are the same device files while I think they are not.

I added code to print out the retrieved major and minor numbers for each file and it printed out different numbers from what I got when I did `ls -l /dev/tty` and `ls -l /dev/tty2`. The major and minor numbers printed out for both `tty` and `tty2` are 0 and 6, while using `ls`, they are 5 and 0 for `tty` and 4 and 2 for `tty2`.

I'm new to Linux and C.
I have double-checked the manpage for `major()` and `minor()` and it seemed that I used these functions correctly. So, I don't know what went wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/sysmacros.h>

#define report_error(x) puts("error") 

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1<<16    

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct stat statbuf1;
    struct stat statbuf2;
    char *fn1;
    char *fn2;

    if (argc < 3) {
            if (argc < 1) {
                    report_error("no command line");
            } else {
                    report_error("Not enough arguments");
            }
    }

    fn1 = argv[1];
    fn2 = argv[2];

    if (lstat(fn1, &statbuf1)) {
            report_error(strerror(errno));
    }
    if (lstat(fn2, &statbuf2)) {
            report_error(strerror(errno));
    }

    if (S_ISCHR(statbuf1.st_mode) && S_ISCHR(statbuf2.st_mode)) {
            unsigned int major1 = major(statbuf1.st_dev);
            unsigned int major2 = major(statbuf2.st_dev);
            unsigned int minor1 = minor(statbuf1.st_dev);
            unsigned int minor2 = minor(statbuf2.st_dev);

            printf("%d  %d\n%d  %d\n", major1, major2, minor1, minor2);

            if (major1 == major2 && minor1 == minor2) {
                    printf("the two device files are equal\n");
                    exit(0);
            }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `stat` instead of `lstat`?

Comment: `report_error` isn't defined, so this isn't a *complete* minimal example.  You're also missing `<stdio.h>` for `printf()` and `<stdlib.h>` for `exit()` (though you could just `return` instead) and of course `<sys/stat.h>` and friends.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Oh that part is actually for another part of my program too, so I had to use `lstat`.

Comment: If I execute your program on a raspberrypi / raspian with arguments `/dev/tty` and  `/dev/tty2` I get "0  0" then "6 6" then "the two device files are equal". To be able to compile I did `#define report_error(x) puts("error")`

Comment: @bruno What if you replace `lstat` with `stat`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. no I just defined `#define report_error(x) puts("error")` and added needed `#include`

Comment: @TobySpeight Yeah, I had those in my code. Just forgot to include them here.

Comment: @bruno Yeah, that's the problem. I don't understand why it's giving `0 0` and `6 6` when it's supposed to give me `5 4` and `0 2` according to `ls`

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have the same result with _stat_ rather than _lstat_

Comment: Wel, there is an answer down there I guess...

Comment: @TomNguyen yes `file /dev/tty` gives `/dev/tty: character special (5/0)` while `file /dev/tty2` gives `/dev/tty2: character special (4/2)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`st_dev` is the **ID of device containing file**, according to the man page.  In other words, the device where the file's *name* resides.  So it's the same as for your `/dev` directory, as you'll see if you use the `stat` command from your shell.

You're interested in **`st_rdev`**, which is **Device ID (if special file)** (again, from the man page).

The `stat` command shows both:

`stat /dev/tty /dev/tty1`

```
  File: /dev/tty
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   character special file
Device: 6h/6d   Inode: 1035        Links: 1     Device type: 5,0
Access: (0620/crw--w----)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    5/     tty)
```

....

```
  File: /dev/tty1
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   character special file
Device: 6h/6d   Inode: 1044        Links: 1     Device type: 4,1
Access: (0620/crw--w----)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    5/     tty)
```

---

### Fixed code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/sysmacros.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int get_char_device(const char *name,
                    unsigned *dev_major, unsigned *dev_minor)
{
    struct stat buf;
    if (stat(name, &buf)) {
        perror(name);
        return 1;
    }
    if (!S_ISCHR(buf.st_mode)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: not a char device\n", name);
        return 1;
    }
    *dev_major = major(buf.st_rdev);
    *dev_minor = minor(buf.st_rdev);
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int major1, minor1, major2, minor2;
    if (get_char_device("/dev/tty1", &major1, &minor1) ||
        get_char_device("/dev/tty2", &major2, &minor2)) {
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%d  %d\n%d  %d\n", major1, major2, minor1, minor2);
    if (major1 == major2 && minor1 == minor2) {
        puts("the two device files are equal");
        return 1;
    }
}
```